# asp.net checkboxlist bind to multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a scenario where I want to bind three different columns to the checkboxlist

```
Datatable dt = GetDataTable("Select col1,col2,col3 from mytable where id={0}");
```

I am able to get the data via my GetDataTable method , and now I want to bind this data to the checkboxlist and the col1,col2 and col3 are boolean values,

Checkboxlist should be able to bind to those bool values. And also I need to know how to get the selected values in order to update my database.

Update : -

Sample data would be like - personal, business, other

DataTable would be -

```
Personal Business Other 
 True     False    True
```

I have to represent this in the checkboxlist

I am doing something like this and I am sure there is a better/easy way of doing this

```
foreach (ListItem item in chkBox.Items)
                            {
                                item.Selected = ShouldItemBeSelected(item.Text);
                            }

      private bool ShouldItemBeSelected(string value)
        {   string id = getId();
            string query = string.Format("select {0} FROM [dbo].[mytable] where ID='{1}'",value, id);
            bool result = false;
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable(query);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                result = Convert.ToBoolean(row[value]);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample data at least 3 rows of what your col1, col2, col3 holds.

Comment: Updated my question, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i think

.aspx page

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsActive" runat="server" 
                      Text='<%# Eval("IsActive") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsActive"))%>'>
        </asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <%-- Checkbox List To binding to sqldatasourc--%>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        DataTextField="IsMultiRole" DataValueField="IsMultiRole">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WaltonCrmConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="select top 10 IsMultiRole from Users"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and .cs file

```
  GridView1.DataSource = DbUtilities.GetDataTableFromSqlQuery("select top 10 IsMultiRole,IsActive from Users");
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

where IsActive is nullable bit field in sql server 2014

EDIT: CheckBox is binded to **IsActive**
and checkboxlist is `IsMultiRole`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question with sample data

Comment: What is your problem with this answer ??? I think both question has same answer !